# With strict null checks, how do I convert a variable that is of type ":string|undefined" to ":string" in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Given that the compiler option `strictNullChecks` is on.

Let's say I have a function that returns a `:string|undefined`, and I have another function that expects a `:string`, and that I have check it is not `undefined`, how do I call the second function, or change `:string|undefined` to `:string`?

Here is some example code:

```
function alpha(): string|undefined {
    return "hello";
}
function beta(s: string) {
    console.log(s);
}
function isEmpty(s: string|undefined): boolean {
    if (s === undefined) {
        return true;
    } else if (s.trim().length === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

const s = alpha();

if (isEmpty(s)) {
    throw new Error("Okay, I manually checked for undefined.");
}

beta(s);
```

This would result in the error:

`Error:(22, 6) TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

Comment: You might want to have a look at [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types). I think they kinda do what you want to do here.

Comment: Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: Version 2.0.3, since i am using strictNullChecks

Answer (score 0):

Usually you would reduce a type using a type guard:

```
if (typeof s === 'string') {
    // s is string
    s.split(',');
} else {
    // s is boolean
    s.valueOf();
}
```

With strict null checks, you can do the same:

```
if (typeof s === 'undefined')
```

Or more specifically in your case:

```
if (typeof s === 'string') {
    beta(s);
}
```

For anyone not using strict null checks, this will of course be different as without this flag, strings can already be undefined.